# How to prove the existence of the limit？

Tags: analysis, limits

> Prove：$\quad\lim_{x\to0\\y\to0}\frac{x^2+y^2}{|x|+|y|}=0$

I don't know how to shrink $\lim_{x\to0\\y\to0}\frac{x^2+y^2}{|x|+|y|}$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803) for information about asking _effective_ homework-related questions.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{x^2+y^2}{|x|+|y|} =\frac{x^2}{|x|+|y|} + \frac{y^2}{|x|+|y|} \le \frac{x^2}{|x|} + \frac{y^2}{|y|} = |x|+|y|$$

Comment: Beautiful method and perfect for avoiding polar coordinates (guess what I did).

Comment: Thanks for your attention and understanding.

Comment: If one wants to be picky, there is a slight zero-divided-by-zero problem with this argument if $x=0$ and $y \neq 0$, or vice versa. (Easily fixed by considering those cases separately, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

I'll forego the image: $$\lim_{x,y\to0} {x^2+y^2\over|x|+|y|}$$ We can write absolute values like so: $|x| = \sqrt{x^2}$. Secondly, because it is a two-dimensional limit, and we can easily work with the squares, I'll convert to polar coordinates. Recall that $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$, and $r^2=x^2+y^2$. Finally, if both x and y are going to 0, that is, both are going toward the origin, then we can say r is going to 0.
Converted, we have $$\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{r^2}{\sqrt{r^2\cos^2(\theta)}+\sqrt{r^2\sin^2(\theta)}}$$. If we pull a common $\sqrt{r^2}$ out of the denominator, and convert the numerator to $\sqrt{r^4}$, we will have $$\lim_{r\to0} \sqrt{r^4\over r^2}\left({1 \over |\cos|+|\sin|}\right)$$
The radical will simplify to $\sqrt{r^2}$ = $|r|$. The limit of the product is equal to the product of the limits: $$\lim_{r\to0}|r|\cdot\lim_{r\to0}\Bbb{(\theta \,stuff)} = 0$$
QED :-)